# angularJs / ui-router : ability to change state during resolve

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have two siblings states, A and B that match the same URL
But I want to go to A or B according to asynchronous Server answer.

I have created a third state, `pivot`.
The aim of "pivot" is to be an intermediate state that will redirect to A or B based on an asynchronous Server call done in its parent state.
`pivot` has a url: `^/?page` attribute in its configuration (but A and B don't have this attribute).
`pivot` is a sibling of `A` and `B`.
`pivot` has a `$state.go()` in it's `onEnter` method.

The problem I encounter is that :
- When the page is displayed for the first time, the parent's state resolve is run twice.
- When clicking on a link that switch from A to B or B to A, an `Error: null is not an object (evaluating '$state.$current.locals[name]')` is triggered.

see http://jsfiddle.net/opeaucelle/6gqygkt7

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            'main': {
                template:  '<ui-view name="body"></ui-view><hr />' +
                'ResolveNames : <li ng-repeat="resolveName in resolveNames track by $index">{{ resolveName }}</li>'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            foo: function($rootScope) {
                if (! $rootScope.resolveNames) {
                    $rootScope.resolveNames = ['root'];
                } else {
                    $rootScope.resolveNames.push('root');
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.app', {
        params: {
            page: null
        },
        resolve: {
            appData: function($q, $rootScope, $stateParams, $timeout) {
                $rootScope.resolveNames.push('root.app');
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $timeout(function() {
                    // calculate target according to Asynchronous process
                    defer.resolve({target: "root.app." + $stateParams.page});
                }, 100);
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.app.pivot', {
        url: '^/?page',
        views: {
            'body@root': {
                template: '<div>default body</div>'
            }
        },
        onEnter: function($state, appData) {
            if (appData.target) {
                $state.go(appData.target); // change state
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.app.a', {
        views: {
            'body@root': {
                template: '<h2>body A</h2>'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.app.b', {
        views: {
            'body@root': {
                template: '<h2>body B</h2>'
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I do ?

Comment: use `$rootScope.$broadcast('change-state', stateName)` and listen in a `.run(function ($rootScope, $state) { $rootScope.$on('change-state', function (e, stateName) { $state.go(stateName); }) });`

Comment: where shall I write "$rootScope.$broadcast('change-state', stateName)" ?

Comment: when you want to navigate to a different state, so if you've found in the resolve that you don't want to proceed, fire off that event

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to do it (see http://jsfiddle.net/opeaucelle/bbb1w0b2/) It does not correspond to my need because parent state resolver should happened only once.